# Excel - Adding animation

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am quite new to Excel and so far it has been fun learning it. I have started using Excel for modelling and i have gained enough expertise at it
I now wanted to go a step ahead and do a bit of designing on Excel
I have a specific requirement. I have 10 sheets in my workbook. I want to add some sort of animation on my first sheet. I currently have a button on my sheet 1.
On click of button it unhides all the 9 sheets and allows me to see modelling stuff in them. On clicking one more time it hides all the 9 sheets again.

Now i want to add one more thing to this. 
On clicking the button i want a light bulb on the sheet to turn on and display a message (along with unhiding the sheets)
On clicking one more time i want the light bulb to turn off and hide the sheets again,

Can someone help me with this animation.

Thanks,
Sachi

Comment: It's pretty easy. What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

Like I said it is very simple. This is how your `Button` and `Bulb` looks like.

[image]

**Shapes used to create the bulb**

1. Straight Connector
2. Oval
3. Cloud

**Code**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If CommandButton1.Caption = "Hide" Then

        '
        '~~> Your code here to Hide the Sheets
        '

        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 2").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)

        CommandButton1.Caption = "Unhide"
    ElseIf CommandButton1.Caption = "Unhide" Then

        '
        '~~> Your code here to Unhide the Sheets
        '

        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 2").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)

        CommandButton1.Caption = "Hide"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

To simply make the button change a shapes fill to yellow try this:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("SHAPE NAME").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
```

The same idea can be applied to change the fill back. I've been playing with actual animation myself a lot lately too, so if you want to get something a bit more fun than the above than try something like the following. (Create a shape called Oval 1 to demo it with, or change the name to your shapes name)

```
Sub bulb()
steps = 300
timelimit = 0.005
increments = 255 / steps
counter = 0
r = 0
g = 0
Do
    DoEvents
    counter = counter + 1
    r = r + increments
    g = g + increments
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(r, g, 0)
    timeout (timelimit)
Loop Until counter = steps
End Sub

Sub timeout(duration_ms As Double)
    Start_Time = Timer
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until (Timer - Start_Time) >= duration_ms
End Sub
```

Will need tweaking to your needs of course but the possibilities playing with this are endless.

Comment: I already had a code with screenshots ready :D was waiting for OP to show some efforts..

Comment: + 1 For posting it before me. :)

Comment: Sorry guys for the late reply.. Thank you for the answers. This is awesome :)